# How can I make the Raphael js print method work on the local machine for French, German,... chars?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, raphael

When I print using the Raphael print method it shows the glyphs right only for the glyphs of that local machine( English keyboard).

If I want to print French Chars(using keyboard short cuts) they either don't show up or show the wrong chars on the local machine. But it works just fine on the ***server side*** .

[Here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/140225334/test-print-Raph.html) is that html page in dropbox server that works fine, but if you download that page in your local system it only show the first 5 English chars right and the rest(French and German chars) would be wrong. You can try this yourself.

How can I make the print method work on the local machine for french, german,... chars as well please. Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the answer : you need to add the following to your html head:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

And this solves the problem!